# Session expiration when using ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have following problem: when my session expires and user clicks on Ajax.Actionlink, Logon page returns as partial page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create an ActionFilterAttribute that implements IAuthorizationFilter
and in OnAuthorization check if the user is logged out,
if he is logged out and this is an Ajax request(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) - set filterContext.Result to a different result.
i return a result with HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
so i can hook to it at the client and react accordingly

never used Ajax.Actionlink, i use jQuery for all my Ajax calls and have a global hook to catch results with error status codes

Comment: And where should I place ActionFilterAttribute?

Comment: you can place it on specific actions,controllers,baseController or register it as a globalFilter at the global.asax

Comment: note that you should put it only on actions/controllers that the user needs to be logged in on order to use - if there are ajax calls to actions where the user can be anonymous - you don't want this filter to interrupt

Answer (score 1):

You will need something like this at the top your actionmethod

```
        if (Session["UserID"] == null && Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
                return Content("<div class=\"error\">Your session was expired. Press Logout and then login again to continue</div>");
        }
```

**Updated**
( you need to specify it when you are checking for your authorization whatever mechanism you have created)

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            List<string> rights = objAuthorization.CheckMemberRightsOnPage("page1");
            if (!rights.Contains("View"))
            {
                if (Session["UserID"] == null && Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    return Content("<div class=\"error\">Your session was expired. Press Logout and then login again to continue</div>");
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Restricted", "UserLogin", new { url = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Substring(1)) });
            }
            ViewData["objAuthorization1"] = rights;


        //  your other things here
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
           ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = "An error occurred: " + ex.Message;
            return View();   } 

    }
```